# SQL division by zero when order by price

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why i get division by zero in this SQL?

I tried so much, like cast, NULLIF and that things but nothing works.

```
$sql = "SELECT *, (cast(price as numeric(20, 4))*100)/cast(pricebefore as numeric(20, 4)) - 100 AS discount FROM products ORDER BY CAST(price AS Float) asc LIMIT $no_of_records_per_page OFFSET $offset";
```

If i kick out

```
(cast(price as numeric(20, 4))*100)/cast(pricebefore as numeric(20, 4)) - 100 AS discount
```

than its working.

But its also working if i kick out

```
ORDER BY CAST(price AS Float) asc
```

But i need them all two... i tried so much but cannot fix it...

Comment: Using postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but checking for pricebefore = 0 at the start should fix it...

```
SELECT *, case when pricebefore = 0 
    then 0 --or you might want 1 or 100 here?
    else (cast(price as numeric(20, 4))*100)
 /cast(pricebefore as numeric(20, 4)) - 100 end AS discount 
FROM products ORDER BY CAST(price AS Float) asc
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

you'll get it if pricebefore is zero-ish (anything that gets cast to 0, like "0" or 0 or NULL or "") - if you just want to get rid of the crash, you can use the GREATEST function with 1, like `/GREATEST(cast(pricebefore as numeric(20, 4)),1)`  - or because of 4 possible decimals, you can use `,0.0001` too, i suppose.. but i doubt your calculations will be accurate afterwards.